# Unit Testing Frameworks for Visual Studio 2012 Cons/Pros

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, testing, visual-studio-2012

I want to get started on Unit Testing in C++ (pure C++, not .NET), since I have never done it before. Always used `assert`  and `cout`. 
So far, the only good Question with detailed answers, I have found is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13699/choosing-a-c-unit-testing-tool-framework, but it is dated to 2008.

I would like to hear some opinions about currently available C++ Unit Testing compatible with Visual Studio 2012. What are their Cons and Pros ? How easy/hard to learn them(i.e availability of learning materials) ? How Popular they are ? Are they being actively developed, supported ?

There are several frameworks that I am aware of: Google's Testing Framework, Boost Testing Lib.

(Also, in addition to Visual Studio, I use Intel Parallel Studio XE 2013, primarily for static analysis)

Comment: It's hard to go wrong with the built in tools if you just want to start out and test a few things.  Some things (like new results each opening a new tab) are a bit primitive, but it mostly gets the job done.  `File->New->Project->Visual C++->Test->Test Project`.

Comment: ebyrob, is it for C++ or C# ?

Comment: C++, but you can create C# test projects as well.

Comment: It's C++/CLI.  If you need pure C++ I know CppUnit used to be pretty decent.  PS - If you're using `cout`, might I suggest log4cpp or one of it's cousins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment we only use the unit testing functionality which comes with VS12 (Premium). We also tested other Frameworks (e.g. NUnit), but for now VS12 testing suits well.

Answer (score 1):

I use TUT unit testing framework: http://tut-framework.sourceforge.net/