# How do I use UIMap Coded UI Test Builder for local testing

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, coded-ui-tests

I have been playing around with testing a simple webforms ASP.NET website application and have come across the UIMap tool in Visual Studio 2010. However I do not know how to use it correctly and it never seems to work.

- Do I need to be running my application in debug mode while recording?
- Once the test is generated is there any way of visually seeing the steps as they are being performed?
- Should I have the browser open before I begin recording, or should I do that once I start and browse to the page that way?
- Can I use Chrome for the browser, or does it have to be IE?
- Does using Dual Screens affect the running of the test?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I need to be running my application in debug mode while recording?

No. You can not use debug/release mode of Visual Studio and do an record at same time. Start the application separately. This has the big advantage that you can test different versions of our application with one set of tests.

> Once the test is generated is there any way of visually seeing the
>   steps as they are being performed?

No. You can get a log from test-run and of course you see the test-run in self, but there is no static graphic ... to be honest I never miss such feature.

> Should I have the browser open before I begin recording, or should I
>   do that once I start and browse to the page that way?

That you can do as you please. Of course you can record the browser start. We start browser before, because browser start is not really a part of the test.

> Can I use Chrome for the browser, or does it have to be IE?

[At the moment IE is the forced browser.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3f68cad8-3624-47ea-a4e4-c56a14d581f7/how-to-execute-my-coded-ui-test-in-chrome-browser?forum=vsautotest) But there are [ways](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj835758%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to use other browsers.

> Does using Dual Screens affect the running of the test?

No. All fine with dual screen. But don't forget when test is running you can't use your mouse and keyboard - you will fight the CUIT ;). We use a separate PC for long CUIT.

**Here are some links which may be helpful for you:**

- [should the coded ui test project share a solution or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329808/testing-an-wpf-app-with-codedui-tests-should-the-coded-ui-test-project-share-a/17336923#17336923)
- [Unit Testing Frameworks for Visual Studio 2012 Cons/Pros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18341809/unit-testing-frameworks-for-visual-studio-2012-cons-pros/18350184#18350184)
- [Which Unit Test framework to use for the projects that requires User Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19219595/which-unit-test-framework-to-use-for-the-projects-that-requires-user-input/19219735#19219735)

Comment: A Coded UI test drives the application being tested by examing what is displayed on the screen and sending keyboard presses and mouse clicks to the correct places. So you can watch the screen as the test is running and so see what is happening as it happens. A consequence of this is that while a Coded UI test is running you must not use the mouse or keyboard for other things or you will probably cause the test to fail.

Comment: @Micha You can test in other browsers, but you'll have to install the Selenium components for Coded UI Cross Browser Testing Visual Studio extension.


http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj835758(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @LuFaMa: Thanks for the link (edit my answer). I here that something like this exists, but getting this is nice. Gave you a +1 on another question for that.

Comment: just as an additional note, there was a bug when I originally posted this question which was causing the problems I was encountering, a patch has since been released so there is no longer an issue...

Comment: @Matthew Pigram: Nice to hear that the bug is solved.